# Forbid overrides from calling base

Tags: c#, overriding, subclassing, virtual-functions

I want to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  public virtual void Foo() {
    this.DoSomethingThatWouldBeFineInASubclassButAnOverrideWouldNotWantToUse();
  }
}
```

Basically, I am doing some work here, and I want a default way of doing it, but if someone is going to override, they should likely NOT be using the default.  It is so easy to put base.Foo() into an override without thinking about it; in fact my IDE does it automatically.  I want to prevent that.  Is it possible?

Comment: You may use the `new`-keyword in order to hide the base-implementation.

Comment: what if you make `DoSomethingThatWouldBeFineInASubclassButAnOverrideWouldNotWantToUse` private? Then it can only be called from `MyClass`

Comment: @NedStoyanov But you could still call `base.Foo()`.

Comment: aha, my bad. IMHO I don't think that is possible. Having `Foo` virtual makes it visible to the child class so they can override it. And if they can override it they can call it.

Comment: Could you elborate more on what exactly that magic method which shouldn't be called from an override is doing? Because any override will be from a subclass, anyway.

Comment: Laying some things out.  The default would be to give all the children the same layout as the parent.  I understand that occasionally, one might want to use the base in an override, but if so, it's very easy to rewrite in the override, and IMO the benefit of being able to call base is not worth the cost of potentially doing so accidentally.

Comment: I have a problem, I "solve" it with inheritance; I now have exponentially growing problems...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is better solved with composition instead of inheritance. Perhaps, using the [strategy pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html):

```
interface ISomeStrategy
{
    void Do();
}

public class MyClass {

    private readonly ISomeStrategy _strategy;

    public MyClass() : this(null) {}

    public MyClass(ISomeStrategy strategy)
    {
        // the default implementation and the user-defined implementation
        // are mutually exclusive
        _strategy = strategy ?? new DefaultStrategy();
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _strategy.Do();
    }

    //secret strategy
    private class DefaultStrategy : ISomeStrategy
    {
        public void Do()
        {
            //secret implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Subclassing:

```
public class Derived : MyClass
{
    public Derived() : base(new DerivedStrategy())
    {

    }
}
```

A bit more verbose, but effective.

Comment: "This is better solved with composition instead of inheritance" - if I could give you +100, I would :)